# Why is the UUID module missing?

Tags: 8

I have two Drupal 8 sites: One has been created with Composer, and the other one has been created with `drupal site:new`.

On the latter, the UUID module appears in the list of modules. I installed it, and added a UUID field to a custom entity.
In the first site, the module doesn't appear in the list of the installable modules.

How can I install the UUID module also in the second site?

Comment: Since D8 the UUID field type is in core: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21UuidItem.php/class/UuidItem/8.6.x

Comment: I know that, sorry if i was not clear enough about that. I thought I have to enable that core module.... because in manage fields there is no uuid field !

Comment: It's not a module you have to enable and by default you don't find base fields in UI, unless you add `setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)` to the base field definition.

Comment: I understand your argument. But I am confused why in the other d8 instance at home I could add an uuid field. 
And I checked my module code, the setting is TRUE for both fields.

Comment: In theory one could add a module extending the core UUID field adding more configuration options. If there is such a module installed only the site owner can answer.

Comment: I found my faulty thoughts when I went home, there is no uuid field to "add" to an entity; What I had in memory was the addition of the entity's uuid field in a view!! 
thanks for trying to help!